# delphi firemonkey: broadcast video

Tags: delphi, video-streaming, firemonkey, android-video-player

How to create an app under ios/android where an user can record a video of himself and broadcast it **in real time** to all his followers. i use Firemonkey and Delphi berlin

Comment: You have to be more specific in your question or else it will be downvoted and closed. SO is for question about code that solves a specific problem. If you really have no idea how to get started, you should ask on an unformal Delphi forum instead, e.g. https://plus.google.com/communities/103113685381486591754 (p.s. I did not down vote your question)

Comment: my question is already very specific, else it's mean i already know the solution :) as their is no 10000 ways to do live video broadcast on firemonkey (if even it's possible) their is no need to be more specific, and i take everything anyone can say about it

Comment: Your question is too broad in scope. It is in no way specific, in the same way as "How can I create an app like Firefox in Delphi?" would be specific.

Comment: @ken so if it's too broad can you at least say me from where to begin ??

Comment: Just like every other programming need - break it into tasks.. The first part is *recording video*, so research that and figure out how to do it in FMX. (Hint: TVideoCaptureDevice.)  Once you have that working (on both Android and iOS), start researching *streaming content* for FMX.  (Hint: Indy.) Once you have that, put them together.

Answer (score -1):

Suggestion: try to use a TWebBrowser and open Google Hangout page inside it.
It's easier than create everything from scratch. ;)